# C# How to configure service to trim trailing zeroes from the result JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, serialization

I have a service, which returns numbers with a floating point the following way:

```
{
   "exampleNumber1": 15.1500,
   "exampleNumber2": 3000.0,
}
```

The desired response is the following:

```
{
   "exampleNumber1": 15.15,
   "exampleNumber2": 3000,
}
```

I am using `NewtonsoftJson` as serializer and I guess to achieve the desired result I need to properly configure it. However I didn't find settings for that in the configuration. What's interesting, Swagger automatically handles & trims the values for me, however when sending a request with postman, the JSON comes in the raw format.
In the example above the values are of type `double` in C# code, but I believe that doesn't matter that much & I want the service to be configured for all the floating numeric types.

Comment: I'd recommend using a JsonConverter so can control the write process.  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: What is the difference? Are you going to print it and put it on the wall as a picture?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use string type.

Comment: @Serge nope, I just need a pretty response JSON, don't ask why :)

Comment: @YiyiYou hm, that may work, but I don't think I can afford that. Great idea thought! Thanks

Comment: @DavidOganov why do you want this in the first place? Trailing decimal zeroes don't matter, in math, JSON, C#, or any other language. If you want no decimals, make sure the type is an integer or long instead of float or decimal

Answer (score -1):

As it was mentioned in the comments, custom JsonConverter is indeed a possible solution for this problem. Posting an answer, just in case someone else will need it in the future.

```
public class DecimalJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(decimal) || objectType == typeof(decimal?);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                    Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue,
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
                                   object value,
                                   JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is { })
        {
            var dec = (decimal)value;
            var trimmedValue = dec.ToString("G29");
            var outValue = decimal.Parse(trimmedValue);
            writer.WriteValue(outValue);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
        }
    }
}
```

Also you'll need to configure NewtonsofJson accordingly:

```
services.AddControllers()
            // other configs
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(option =>
                {
                    // other configs
                    option.SerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new DecimalJsonConverter() };
                })
            // other configs
            ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why? There's nothing wrong with the generated JSON. This should be *downvoted* unless there's a very clear, valid, *exceptional* reason. In fact, arbitrarily changing the type of `exampleNumber2` to `int` instead of `decimal` is *a bug*. If you use this in an API with an OpenAPI schema, the response violates the schema

Comment: @CodeCaster this answer changes the type from `decimal` to `int`. That's a bug, hence the downvote - this answer can cause harm. I wouldn't downvote if the type hadn't changed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, it doesn't? "G29" just trims trailing zeroes.

Comment: @CodeCaster `"exampleNumber2": 3000.0` changed to `"exampleNumber2": 3000`. While ECMA-404/RFC-8259 don't make a distinction between integers and decimals, Swagger/OpenAPI [does](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#numbers). So do code generation tools, like VS's `Paste JSON as Classes`. Both the question *AND* answer should come with a big warning, explaining the circumstances that make this a valid conversion

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nobody says they're using OpenAPI here, and you can add a format hint to numbers. `42` can be a float (number) as well as an integer. I get what you're getting at, but it's such a far-fetched caveat...